# Как подставить новое значение в цикле на Python?

Tags: python, list, циклы

У меня есть такой отрывок кода:

```
    for i in [prices]:
    nick = [i][0][0]["data"][0]["advertiser"]["nickName"]

    print(nick)
```

Мне нужно вывести 500 имен. Если запустить код как есть, то выведется первое имя. А еще я могу сделать так:

```
    for i in [prices]:
    nick_1 = [i][0][0]["data"][0]["advertiser"]["nickName"]
    nick_2 = [i][0][1]["data"][0]["advertiser"]["nickName"]
    nick_3 = [i][0][2]["data"][0]["advertiser"]["nickName"]
    *******
    nick_500 = [i][0][499]["data"][0]["advertiser"]["nickName"]

    print(nick_1, nick_2, nick_3, .... nick_500)
```

И так всё будет работать. Но для всех 500 имен это получится слишком большой код. Подскажите, есть какой-нибудь более изящный код? Очень прошу, с примером. Если просто сказать "пропиши циклы" я не ничего не пойму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так подойдет?

```
res = [[i][0][j]["data"][0]["advertiser"]["nickName"] for j in range(500)]
print(*res)
```

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо огромное! Подскажите, а для чего звездочка в принте? Без неё срабатывает, но следом идет ошибка

Comment: Почитал на эту тему информацию, всё понял) Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Можно с круглыми скобками